# When I export my Android Studio project to a zip file it no longer works correctly

Tags: android

The last three times I have exported my Android Studio project file to a zip file and sent it to my trainer it doesn't work for my trainer. When I re-open it after sending it to him it no longer works for me. Prior to exporting the file it works perfectly. Is there any reason this would be happening? I need to pass my assignment but because of this issue I have had to re-build my app three times and I don't have time to do that again. I have included two screen shots: The first is what the app looks like when you add an item to the 'To Do List' when it works. The second is what happens after exporting the zip file and then re-opening the app. You cannot add an item to the list even though it says it has been saved. I haven't included any code as I am not sure what part to include. Please help as I am beyond frustrated.

[Item has been added to 'To Do List' list successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FAQH.png)

[Item has been added but no item shows on list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lC4A.png)

Comment: why are you exporting it as a zip ? make use of proper version control like git and share it somewhere else, like github

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have to upload it on the Internet through my course submissions so the only way is to upload a zip file as it's too large otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way go to

> project tab->select project from  dropdown ->right click you will get list of option->Show in Explorer->zip the folder and send where you want.
> it will run without any problem
> [image: click here for screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I will have to try that once I re-build my app back to a working state.